# How can i use this Code for any number rather than just For number 1

Tags: php, arrays

This code is just for calculating the Unit 1 and showing the length of unit 1 But how can I get the Output Of any Input  Number?

So in this There is array{ $map} Which Contains the value of Each units so now i want to know that how can i get the Output of any random number in the Input.

```
<?php
// map base 'meter'
$map = [
    'kilometer'  => 0.001, 'hectometer' => 0.01, 'decameter' => 0.1, 'meter' => 1, 'decimeter' => 10,
    'centimeter' => 100, 'millimeter' => 1000, 'micrometer' => 1000000, 'nanometer' => 1000000000, 'mile' => 0.00062,
    'yard'       => 1.09361, 'foot' => 3.28084, 'inch' => 39.3700787, 'nauticalmile' => 0.0005399568,
];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fromUnit = $_POST['fromUnit'];
    $toUnit = $_POST['toUnit'];
    $result = $map[$toUnit] / $map[$fromUnit];
    echo "1 $fromUnit = " . $result . " $toUnit";
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fromConvertionUnit">Convert From</label>
        <select name="fromUnit" id="fromUnit" class="form-control">
            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">Micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="toConvertionUnit">Convert To</label>
        <select name="toUnit" id="toUnit" class="form-control">
            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">Micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' name="submit">
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly, but why don't you just multiply it? Let's say, you've got the random number input in `$_POST['number']`, then you would just use: `echo "$_POST['number'] $fromUnit = " . $_POST['number'] * $result . " $toUnit";` for example.

Comment: yaa thats correct thanks i was not getting that due to Iam newbie in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try to add a variable "amount" and take it as an input from the user.**

```
<?php
// map base 'meter'
$map = [
    'kilometer' => 0.001, 'hectometer' => 0.01, 'decameter' => 0.1, 'meter' => 1, 'decimeter' => 10,
    'centimeter' => 100, 'millimeter' => 1000, 'micrometer' => 1000000, 'nanometer' => 1000000000, 'mile' => 0.00062,
    'yard' => 1.09361, 'foot' => 3.28084, 'inch' => 39.3700787, 'nauticalmile' => 0.0005399568,
];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];  // The amount variable
    $fromUnit = $_POST['fromUnit'];
    $toUnit = $_POST['toUnit'];
    $result = $map[$toUnit] / $map[$fromUnit];
    echo "$amount $fromUnit = " . ($amount * $result) . " $toUnit";
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="amount">
            Amount
            <input id="amount" name="amount">    <!--The input of the amount -->
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fromConvertionUnit">Convert From</label>
        <select name="fromUnit" id="fromUnit" class="form-control">
            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">Micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="toConvertionUnit">Convert To</label>
        <select name="toUnit" id="toUnit" class="form-control">
            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">Micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' name="submit">
```